# reactjs passing array of objects from parent state by props to child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My code is as below:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {arr: [{id: 1, val: 11}, {id: 2, val: 22}]}
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <Child Arr = {this.state.arr} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class Child extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.changeVal = this.changeVal.bind(this)
        this.arr = props.Arr
    }

    changeVal(){
        this.arr[0].val *= 2
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <input type='button' value='change val' onClick={this.changeVal} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

What I realized is that after pressing button props in child and state in parent changed. 
[image]
[image]
I thought that when I assigned props to local variable:

```
this.arr = props.Arr
```

I can change this local variable without any affect to props or state from which it came.

Is it a correct solution to copy passed props when assigning it to local variable (code below), or is it generally bad idea to use more complex state - e.g. array of objects etc. ?

```
class Child extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.changeVal = this.changeVal.bind(this)
        //this.arr = props.Arr
        this.arr = this.copyArrayOfObjects(props.Arr)
    }

    copyArrayOfObjects(arrToCopy){
        if(arrToCopy == null){
            return null
        }

        let arrToRet = []
        for(let i=0; i<arrToCopy.length; i++){
            let obj = {...arrToCopy[i]}
            arrToRet.push(obj)
        }  

        return arrToRet
    }

    changeVal(){
        this.arr[0].val *= 2
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <input type='button' value='change val' onClick={this.changeVal} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
this.arr = [...props.Arr]
```

Doing above didn't really solved problem and neither I was happy with reactjs (documentation) alternate solutions recommended. Right from the beginning ReactJS claim that the state is private, props are read-only, data flow one direction..etc. to its component and all of a sudden it behave strange when object with Arrays passed as prop. It is a design flaw in Reactjs.

I used lodash (`npm i --save lodash`) and then cloned the object while passing from parent to child. It solved my problem once for all and application started behaving as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Objects are passed as reference not as value. so by changing value in child you're eventually changing value at that reference.

```
this.arr = props.Arr
```

change this line to

```
this.arr = [...props.Arr]
```

This a worth reading [fully controlled component](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#recommendation-fully-controlled-component) if your component is fully dependent on props and you don't need local state.

Comment: well, none of the document reading helped me, care to explain how to fix this?